# Is it possible to meet someone outside at Delhi IGI airport during 3 hours layover before international flight

Tags: air-india

I am travelling from Bangalore to Vienna by air India with a 3 hour layover at Delhi IGI airport. Can I meet my parents at Delhi IGI airport during layover time to handover a packet?

Comment: yes, only if you have to do the check in for vienna at delhi airport and not in banglore. Then you can exit the airport in delhi and you have to collect your luggauge ( if you have any) and then again go to the departure and then get the boarding pass to vienna at delhi airport. Otherwise No.

Comment: @NRandhawa: That would be a somewhat strange arrangement. How is it enforced -- do they stop all passengers leaving the airport and check that they don't have onward flights?

Comment: @HenningMakholm This is india and you can't enter the airport without valid ticket and passport ( not even checkin area). When he wants to go out and checked to vienna in banglore, he has to go through Immigration because he is in international transist zone.

Comment: @NRandhawa: Why would he be in an international transit zone after arriving on a flight from Bangalore to Delhi?

Comment: @HenningMakholm see the answer below! He has explained it what I trying to say.

Comment: Can you post your itinerary?

Comment: @NRandhawa You can enter the terminal with a boarding card and ID too.

Comment: @RedBaron Yes, in this case so called Adhar Card which is kind of national ID in India. Since you can not enter india with US/EU national ID or driving liecence so these will not be accepted.

Comment: @dipak So what happened? I am curious to know because I never made it out of Delhi airport in less than 30 mins.

Answer (score 1):

I see two cases:

1. If your flight from Bangalore to Delhi is from a different service provider then you have to collect your bags and check-in again. The bag check-in area is very close to the exits which means you can go out and come back easily. On a side note, last time I took a Vistara flight from Bangalore to Delhi and Air India from Delhi to Vienna. Time gap of 3 hours was barely enough to get my bags checked in, go through the security, immigration and board the flight. So rethink even if it takes only 15 mins.
2. If your baggage is directly transferred through the airlines, then you directly head towards international transfers, security, immigration and boarding area. So no exits nearby. It would be much of a hassle to go out and get in without considerable delay.

So rethink your plan to deliver the package by hand and choose a reliable courier service. `In the grand scheme of things, this is a speeding ticket.`

Comment: As BLR-DEL will be a domestic flight, why can't OP head for the exits (with other passengers) and re-enter again showing his boarding pass and ID to terminal security and pass security/immigration like a normal traveller embarking on international flight from Delhi?

Comment: @RedBaron OP certainly can. Lets assume the boarding closes latest 30 mins before the departure. So you have 2:30 hours to go out like a normal domestic passenger, come back, clear security, immigration and head to boarding gate. In my experience, getting to the exit from the time you disembark plane takes an average of 30 mins in Delhi. It's not impossible but a hassle none the less.

Comment: Without baggage to collect (scenario 2), I think 30 minutes to disembark and exit the airport seems _very_ pessimistic. OP has to clear immigration and security in any case (even if they opt for domestic/international transfer over exit and entry into airport) so I think those times can be treated as constant.